# An intergral with variable upper limit

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, indefinite-integrals

Let
 $$\psi \left(x \right)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt,x\in (0,1).$$
Show
$$\forall x\in (0,1), \psi\left(x \right)=?$$

---

I return the old variable $t$ by the substitution $s=ln(1-t)$,and then get 
$$\int_{0}^{\ln(1-x)}\frac{se^{s}}{e^{s}-1}ds.$$
but seemingly,this integration  is not easy for me to solve as well as  the first one.

---

**NOTE :**

**In fact，  I want use the result of this question to find *the sum functions of power series* :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{x}^{n}}{n^{2}},\left(0<x<1 \right).$$**

Comment: Your integral is just the negative of the dilogarithm function: $\psi{(x)}=-\operatorname{Li}_2{(x)}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Expand $\ln(1-t)$ into its well-known Taylor series, then reverse the order of summation and integration. The result will be a [polylogarithmic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: In fact，  I want use the result of this question to find the sum functions of power series :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{x}^{n}}{n^{2}},\left(0<x<1 \right).$$

Comment: @Jay: Then I am afraid that, unless *x* has some specific values, such as $0$, $\pm1$, or $\dfrac12$, your sum is not known to possess a closed form.

Comment: Thanks,what you said has some points.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding Lucian's answer, over $[0,1)$ we have:
$$\log(1-t) = -\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{t^j}{j},$$
hence:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt=-\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^j}{j^2}=-\operatorname{Li}_2(x).$$

Comment: It is just the dilogarithm function, that is not an "elementary" function in the usual meaning.